# Using index.html files in Wolfram Cloud sites

Tags: wolfram-cloud, webservices

**Cross post from Wolfram Community:** http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1250045

---

Part as exercise, part so I could write data-science blog posts I built a website builder using Mathematica that sets up sites in the cloud.

As an example site, here is a paclet server website I set up: https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/PacletServer/main.html

Unfortunately, to get this to work I had to remap my site's index.html file to a main.html file, because when I try to view the site at the index.html either by explicitly routing there or by going to the implicit view I am pushed back to the implicit view and given a 500 error.

Note that I cannot copy the index.html file to the site root i.e.,

```
CopyFile[
 CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/PacletServer/index.html"],
 CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/PacletServer", Permissions->"Public"]
 ]
```

as I get a `CloudObject::srverr` failure

I can't even set up a permanent redirect like so:

```
CloudDeploy[
 Delayed@HTTPRedirect[
   "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/PacletServer/main.html",
   <|"StatusCode" -> 301|>
   ],
 "server",
 Permissions -> "Public"
 ]

CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/server"]
```

As while this apparently worked, going to that site causes my browser to spin infinitely and before finally giving up.

Even more, all of these possible hacks are ugly and I'd much rather work with the standard website setup.

How can I do this?